# Spark SQL Library

Tags: pyspark, databricks

We've just had someone claim to us that we should avoid using the Spark SQL library within Databricks due to reliability. I've never run across an issue with using the library (although I am still in the novice area regarding spark/Databricks), can anyone clarify or are they trying to lead us down a garden path?

Answer (score 1):

Spark SQL is a Spark module for structured data processing. It provides a programming abstraction called DataFrames and can also act as a distributed SQL query engine.
It is based on [Shark SQL AmpLab Project](https://amplab.cs.berkeley.edu/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/shark_sigmod2013.pdf) and it is adopted as an Apache Spark module.

Spark SQL also includes a cost-based optimizer, columnar storage, and code generation to make queries fast. At the same time, it scales to thousands of nodes and multi-hour queries using the Spark engine, which provides full mid-query fault tolerance, without having to worry about using a different engine for historical data.

Hence, do not worry about using it in your projects. It's a highly mature and battle-tested library.